# Stop ADF pipeline execution if there is no data

Tags: azure-data-factory

I must stop the execution of an adf pipeline if there is no data in a table, but this should not generate an error, it should only stop the execution, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if activity wherein 1st validate whether there is any data in table, if yes then use other activities within True case else do nothing.
It would exit without any issues

Comment: perfect thank you, I'm going to try this ingenious solution

Comment: Glad it could help you. Can you please upvote and accept it as answer as it might benefit other community members as well